# Ending the Game in Unity for a vertical game where you jump on blocks

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have created a game in unity in which you jump onto blocks to increase vertically while your points increase as well. Although I have tried a couple ways to end the game none of them ended up working. Would anyone have any ways to end the game, preferably through collision?

Comment: "Ending the game" is code that is entirely controlled by you. You decide when it happens, how it happens, and what happens when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can select wich objects you want to end the game with. If you want to end the game when the object has a collision with a wall you could tag the wall object with the word "Wall" and load an scene called "Game Over", which contains something like the score, a reset button or something like that.

```
 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision exampleCol) {
     if(exampleCol.collider.tag == "Wall")
     {
         SceneManager.LoadScene("Game Over");
     }
 }
```

If you just want to load a Game Over screen when the object has a collision with any object just write this:

```
 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision exampleCol) {
         SceneManager.LoadScene("Game Over");
 }
```

If you don't want to load a Game Over scene, just put this:

```
     void OnCollisionEnter(Collision exampleCol) {
         Application.Quit();
     }
```

There are a lot of combinations, it depends on you. Attach this code to the main object.

Comment: If *`there are a lot of combinations`* that's a good reason to flag / vote to close "too broad."

Comment: I tried to use a similar script before but the problem I faced was that the player did not collide with the walls and instead just passed through them.

Comment: @CemOzsoy you have to attach a collider to each object

Comment: @Gyntonic I tried the edge collider 2D with the platform effector but the player would land on it and stay there. What else can I use?

Comment: @CemOzsoy have you tried with OnCollisionEnter2D(collision2D exampleCol){}... instead of OnCollisionEnter(....)?